# Proper NodeJS code to delete old files from a tmp uploads folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the following code to delete old files from a tmp upload directory:

```
       fs.readdir( dirPath, function( err, files ) {
            if ( err ) return console.log( err );
            if (files.length > 0) {
                files.forEach(function( file ) {
                    var filePath = dirPath + file;
                    fs.stat( filePath, function( err, stat ) {
                        if ( err ) return console.log( err );
                        var livesUntil = new Date();
                        livesUntil.setHours(livesUntil.getHours() - 1);
                        if ( stat.ctime < livesUntil ) {
                            fs.unlink( filePath, function( err ) {
                                if ( err ) return console.log( err );
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

I run it once an hour.  This works, most of the time.
However I am finding that occasionally uploads disappear unexpectedly in the middle of uploading. 
I *think* what is happening is that this code gets run while a file is actually in the middle of uploading, before stat.ctime is set - and so it gets deleted before it is finished.
Any suggestions on how I can prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can upload to another directory and move the file when it is done.

Comment: Consider naming your anonymous functions and composing this sequence afterward. Also consider your logical branching. The `files.length > 0` is not necessary. A good rule of thumb is to consider indentation to be a measure of badness. You should also consider adding some comments to help the reader out. Be liberal with vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

Why not clean up on each upload?

```
var fs = require('fs');

var fsio;
(function (fsio) {
    var uploader = (function () {
        function uploader() {
        }
        uploader.prototype.writeFile = function (fn, data, cb) {
            var tempDest = '/tmp/' + fn;

            // .. your write logic ..

            // cleanup
            cb(tempDest);
        };

        uploader.prototype.cleanup = function (fileDest) {

            // .. your cleanup logic - move or copy/del ..

            fs.unlink(fileDest);
        };

        uploader.prototype.upload = function (fn, data) {
            this.writeFile(fn, data, this.cleanup);
        };
        return uploader;
    })();
    fsio.uploader = uploader;
})(fsio || (fsio = {}));
```

usage:

```
var fileupload = new fsio.uploader();
fileupload.upload("monkey.gif", []);
```